# How can I add a keyboard shortcut regardless if the focus is on an iframe?

Tags: tampermonkey

I run a tampermonkey script adding keyboard shortcuts to a page. With `document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {}` it catches a key stroke well until the focus is on an iframe on this page. Then it stops working.

How can I have the script listen to the keyboard regardless if the focus is on an iframe or not?

Comment: If the iframe's URL is http or https then add it to `@match` so your script will run inside the iframe too. Otherwise add a listener using frameElem.contentWindow.addEventListener.

Comment: I added the iframes url and tampermonkey indicates that it matches 2 times but the key is still not recognized when within this frame.